# How to implement radio button in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, dlradiobutton

I want to add buttons like radio button. i have created round rect button but no idea about radio button.

How can I do it? This how I implement checkbox button feature.

any help please ?

Comment: read this http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uibutton-tutorial-radio-buttons/ i hope it can help you

Answer (score 8):

The best way of achieving this is setting a normal and a selected image for each button. You can then easily switch each button on or off using the selected property:

```
myButton.selected = YES;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,it  partially worked..
the problem is when try to select the button again, it doesn't get selected.
any idea?

Comment: ok, got it.. set radioButtonSetController.selectedIndex = NSNotFound thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct UI for radio button you have to use images on UIbutton so that you can replace the checked images when a user press on the button just like tableview check/ uncehck functionality .It is just a trick by which you can make feel of a radio button.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a controller for handling the logic behind an array of radio buttons. It's open source and on GitHub, check it out!

https://github.com/goosoftware/GSRadioButtonSetController

Comment: hi Simon! I tried to use GSRadioButtonSetController, it works very nicely.Thanks.
But how to deselect the buttons? I tried 'myButton.selected = YES;'
but when try to select the button again, it doesn't get selected.
any idea?

Comment: ok, got it..
set `radioButtonSetController.selectedIndex = NSNotFound`
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DLRadioButton](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton)! It supports not only radio buttons but also checkboxes. If you have any questions, please feel free to leave a comment.

[image: radio button for iOS]